# My Android app crashes when trying to store SQLite data

Tags: java, android, sqlite, button, crash

I tried to import an SQLite sample code into my Android application to save and manage my data through SQLite, using a ListView.

In this SQLite sample that implements an AddressBook when I fill in the text fields of a new contact and I press "Save" button to save them to my SQLite, then  my Android app crashes, displaying that unfortunately my application has terminated.I believe that my problem is focused on the button Save(button1) and especially line: android:onClick="run"  but I don't understand the exact problem.For your convenience method "run" is implemented in DisplayContact.java archive.

The code of my button1 in my activity_display_contact.xml layout is:

```
<Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextCity"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
      android:onClick="run"
      android:text="@string/save" />
```

The code of my DisplayContact.java which is responsible for tha layout of ListView is :

```
package com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets;

import com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets1.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DisplayContact extends Activity {

   int from_Where_I_Am_Coming = 0;
   private DBHelper mydb ;
   TextView name ;
   TextView phone;
   TextView email;
   TextView street;
   TextView place;
   int id_To_Update = 0;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_contact);
      name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
      phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
      email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextStreet);
      street = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
      place = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextCity);

      mydb = new DBHelper(this);

      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
      if(extras !=null)
      {
         int Value = extras.getInt("id");
         if(Value>0){
            //means this is the view part not the add contact part.
            Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);
            id_To_Update = Value;
            rs.moveToFirst();
            String nam = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME));
            String phon = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONE));
            String emai = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL));
            String stree = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_STREET));
            String plac = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_CITY));
            if (!rs.isClosed()) 
            {
               rs.close();
            }
            Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            name.setText((CharSequence)nam);
            name.setFocusable(false);
            name.setClickable(false);

            phone.setText((CharSequence)phon);
            phone.setFocusable(false); 
            phone.setClickable(false);

            email.setText((CharSequence)emai);
            email.setFocusable(false);
            email.setClickable(false);

            street.setText((CharSequence)stree);
            street.setFocusable(false); 
            street.setClickable(false);

            place.setText((CharSequence)plac);
            place.setFocusable(false);
            place.setClickable(false);
           }
      }
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
      if(extras !=null)
      {
         int Value = extras.getInt("id");
         if(Value>0){
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_contact, menu);
         }
         else{
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
         }
      }
      return true;
   }

   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
   { 
      super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
      switch(item.getItemId()) 
   { 
      case R.id.Edit_Contact: 
      Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      name.setEnabled(true);
      name.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
      name.setClickable(true);

      phone.setEnabled(true);
      phone.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
      phone.setClickable(true);

      email.setEnabled(true);
      email.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
      email.setClickable(true);

      street.setEnabled(true);
      street.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
      street.setClickable(true);

      place.setEnabled(true);
      place.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
      place.setClickable(true);

      return true; 
      case R.id.Delete_Contact:

      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setMessage(R.string.deleteContact)
     .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            mydb.deleteContact(id_To_Update);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
         }
      })
     .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User cancelled the dialog
         }
      });
      AlertDialog d = builder.create();
      d.setTitle("Are you sure");
      d.show();

      return true;
      default: 
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 

      } 
   } 

   public void run(View view)
   {    
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      if(extras !=null)
      {
         int Value = extras.getInt("id");
         if(Value>0){
            if(mydb.updateContact(id_To_Update,name.getText().toString(), phone.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString(), street.getText().toString(), place.getText().toString())){
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
               Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.MainActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
             }      
            else{
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
            }
         }
         else{
            if(mydb.insertContact(name.getText().toString(), phone.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString(), street.getText().toString(), place.getText().toString())){
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            }       
            else{
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
      }
   }
}
```

and the code of my Logcat is the following:

```
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method run(View) in the activity class com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.ImageTargets for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3050)
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: run [class android.view.View]
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3043)
04-07 04:09:25.113: E/AndroidRuntime(7943):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Do you have an activity named ImageTargets?

Comment: Yes I have.It is the main activity of my project.In my Imagetargets code I use setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_contact); to access the ListView of my SQLite.My SQLite is implemented in three classes, named DBHelper.java, MainActivity.java(this is the main activity of the sample SQLite project that I inserted to my own project) and DisplayContact.java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird: Your Java code creates an Activity called "DisplayContact" but the stacktrace says it cannot find an onClick handler called "run" in an Activity called "ImageTargets". I would check the way your development project has been set up.

Comment: I have an activity called ImageTargets and it is the main activity of my project.In my Imagetargets code I use setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_contact); to access the ListView of my SQLite.My SQLite is implemented in three classes, named DBHelper.java, MainActivity.java(this is the main activity of the sample SQLite project that I inserted to my own project) and DisplayContact.java. Do you believe that I have to insert "run" into my ImageTargets.java or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes!!! You have to insert run in the Activity class, which is ImageTargets in your case.

Comment: And btw. the on... Methods in your DisplayContact class are probably never called if you don't start DisplayContact as an Activity. So you will have to move the parts that your run method relies on to ImageTargets as well.